# Why will the compiler accept an invalid syntax call (<?>method) when statically called?

Tags: java, generics, methods

Is there a reason that a Java Generic Method cannot be called without the Static/Instance reference before the method? Like "case 2" and "case 5" on the example code.

In other words, why can we call a normal method without the static/instance reference (like in "case 3") and in Generic Methods we can't?

```
public class MyClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClass.<String>doWhatEver("Test Me!"); // case 1

    <String>doWhatEver("Test Me2!"); // case 2 COMPILE ERROR HERE

    doSomething("Test Me 3!"); // case 3 (just for compare)

    new MyClass().<String>doMoreStuff("Test me 4"); // case 4

}

public void doX(){
    <String>doMoreStuff("test me 5"); // case 5 COMPILE ERROR HERE
}


public static <T> void doWhatEver(T x){
    System.out.println(x);
}

public static void doSomething(String x){
    System.out.println(x);
}

public <T> void doMoreStuff(T x){
    System.out.println(x);
}

}
```

Comment: AFAIK `<T>someMethod()` is not a valid syntax..

Comment: It's a syntax error. You don't need the `<...>` though, the compiler will generally infer the correct type.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard yes, I know, but is not a syntax error, it compile and run if you comment the case 2 and case 5. And there are cases, some API's you must use these syntax.

Comment: @RC. where are you seeing this "<T>someMethod()" ? is <T>someMethod(T t) . and this is legal code

Comment: @NESPowerGlove yes, beacause you can call without the instance/static reference with a normal method, and a generic method you can't...

Comment: By "is there a reason" do you mean "is there a reason that the language was designed this way"? If so, this is probably off-topic for SO, since it's not really a programming question... it's a language design question, and one which only the language designers can probably answer.

Comment: `<String>doWhatEver("Test Me2!");` <= here (if it's legal code you should not get a compilation error). see http://imgur.com/HYokUP4

Comment: @yshavit i don't think this is offtopic. I'm studying generic and collections for 1z0-804, and all the things we can't do in generics have a reason explained, but I just can't see why this is not possible calling the generic methods

Comment: How this gets put "on hold" as opinion based is kind of a mystery to me..

Comment: @RC. this is part of the question, why if you don't put the reference instance/static in front of, I doesn't compile? And with no generic methods, you can

Comment: lol , this is not a opinion based question. I don't have a opinion for that, I just want to know why...

Comment: @RC  "put on hold as primarily opinion-based by *RC.*, yshavit, NESPowerGlove, Javier, rgettman 7 mins ago " ...Is it really a mystery to you?

Comment: According to me, it compiles and runs fine with proper syntax, see https://ideone.com/KqKM5f (and my close vote was "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting." - cheers)

Comment: @RC. and why the syntax was incorrect?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/ (final comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You don't need to specify `<String>` for case 1 and 4, the compiler will handle this for you.
- Now let's try to run your exemple and see what happen.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - illegal start of expression

It's that much simple, the answer to your question is because the syntax is invalid, it was not meant to be used that way in the `javac` specifications.

However, this has nothing to do with being `static` or not. Try it in a constructor removing the static keyword to `doWhatEver` method :

```
public MyClass()
{
    <String>doWhatEver("Test Me2!"); //does not compile
    doWhatEver("Test Me2!"); //compile
}

public <T> void doWhatEver(T x){
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

---

Now if you are wondering why `MyClass.<String>doWhat..` compiled while `<String>doWhat..` did not compile even if we modify the static keyword, let's have a look at the generated bytecode.

Your line will be compiled to this :

```
6: invokestatic  #5                  // Method doWhatEver:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Which correct the syntax error you made, but why ?.

Try compiling for example these two lines

```
MyClass.<String>doWhatEver("Test Me2!");
MyClass.doWhatEver("Test Me3!");
```

then run `javap -v` on the .class file and you will notice that the both call was compiled to the same bytecode.

```
4: ldc           #4                  // String Test Me2!
6: invokestatic  #5                  // Method doWhatEver:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
9: ldc           #6                  // String Test Me3!
11: invokestatic  #5                  // Method doWhatEver:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

In the case were you call the non-static method, the generated bytecode will be `invokevirtual` instead :

```
17: invokevirtual #8                  // Method doWhatEver2:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

My guess is that `invokestatic` will search directly in the constant pool (where static method are stored) for the method corresponding to the specified call and will ommit the type declaration, while `invokevirtual` will search in the actual class.

Comment: very good answer, tnx so much. And i just have found the specification for the syntax. The rule is, if is a Generic Method, you must call with the super() / this / reference variable / or Class (if static).